# Formatting Exception when parsing textbox into double

Tags: c#, parsing, textbox, formatting, double

```
A = double.Parse(ABox.Text);
B = double.Parse(BBox.Text);
C = double.Parse(CBox.Text);
a = double.Parse(a_Box.Text);
b = double.Parse(b_Box.Text);
c = double.Parse(c_Box.Text);
```

Every time this code is run in my system, it throws an Formatting exception.  The textBoxes are empty when the error appears, do they have to have at least a zero in them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

(An empty string can't be parsed into a double)

Instead of Parse you can consider using [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx):

```
double number;

if (Double.TryParse(ABox.Text, out number))
{
    ...
}
else
{    
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I know! Would 'TryParse' be better to use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Parse will throw an exception if the input is an empty string. You'll either need to check first whether the textbox is empty before parsing it or you can use [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx).